# MoSync - Edit video

Tags: c++, mp4, mosync

After making a small video recorder application and being able to play that video again. I would like to make the possibility to pick X seconds from the video and put that into a new .MP4 file (or overwrite the old one, that would be even better).

I am using the MoSync C++ Native UI and VideoViewer. I know I can get the position and that part is all fine, and according to the MoSync documentation.

```
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
maWidgetGetProperty(videoViewHandle, 
                    MAW_VIDEO_VIEW_CURRENT_POSITION, 
                    buf, 
                    BUFFER_SIZE);
int seconds = 5;
//So here I need to make a new file ranging from buf to buf + seconds
```

However, I have absolutely no clue as to where to look for this. Should I use mp4 header files and create my own mp4 (how is this even done? and is this cross-compatible?).

Will appreciate any advice/help you can offer!